# Copy spreadsheet cells into an array?

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to write a program to take selected cells from a spreadsheet and dump each cell into it's own element in an array once copied using an alternative keyboard shortcut. Is there a way to do this using Mono?

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When copying a column from a spread sheet to the clipboard, each cell is formatted with /n between each cells contents. Therefore splitting each cell was easily achieved with the code snippet below.

I was able to achieve the desired outcome by this by using sample code:

```
string test = "1\n2\n3\n";
    string[] result = test.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```